# Stored Procedure for generating report from comma separated values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My scenario is below:

I have a profile table as below

```
ProfileID   int
FirstName   varchar(50)
LastName    varchar(100)
DateOfBirthDay  varchar(100)
DateOfBirthMonth    varchar(100)
DateOfBirthYear varchar(100)
Gender  varchar(100)
Address1    varchar(100)
Address2    varchar(100)
City    varchar(100)
Province    varchar(100)
PostalCode  varchar(100)
PhoneNumber varchar(100)
WorkNumber  varchar(100)
CellNumber  varchar(100)
EmailAddress    varchar(100)
```

I also have table to store the different conditions for each profile as below:

```
ProfileId   int
CurrentWeight   float
HeightUnit  varchar(50)
CurrentHeight   float
Occupation  varchar(50)
Conditions  varchar(MAX)
Medications varchar(MAX)
Is_Pregnant bit
Diseases    varchar(MAX)
Allergy_Food    varchar(MAX)
Supplements_Taken   varchar(MAX)
Programs_Attended   varchar(MAX)
Knowledge_Source    varchar(MAX)
DateOfPhysicalExam  datetime
MoreInformation varchar(MAX)
```

Data is stored for each record in this table as below:(sample)

```
False   10,12,  119,    138,    145,147,149,
```

It just stores the id of the conditions ids as comma separated values. There is a master table which stores the value associated with each id as below:

```
    5   1   Conditions  Organ transplant
    6   1   Conditions  Recent heart attack (within the last 6 months)  A
    7   1   Conditions  Recent stroke (within the last 6 months)    A
    8   2   Medications Adderral
    9   2   Medications Aptivus Aptivus A
    10  2   Medications Atripla Atripla A
    11  2   Medications Chloramphenicol 
    12  2   Medications Coumadin    
    13  2   Medications Crixivan    
.................................
```

Now I need to create a report using stored procedure to fetch each customers profile along with the conditions, medications etc.... in the format below:

```
id   Name    Age    Occupation    Diseases   Medications   Is_Preg    Supplements_Taken

10001  TestName 59  Office   Asthma, Blood Pressure    Heparin, Aptivus, Indocin  False
```

How do I go with this?

Comment: What specifically are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string) function will work for you.

You can join the table that is returned to condition/medication lookup table.